# Ionic 2 package build ios --profile prod not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Alright, here goes.

I'm using Ionic 2, and have a 90% ready production build. I want to upload it to itunnes connect so I can publish it to TestFlight.

I'm able to `ionic package build ios --profile dev` and it generates the build successfully. No problem. However when I use the `prod` profile, which has the production certificates in the Ionic cloud it fails miserably with this:

`Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.`

I've generated and revoked at least 10 certificates and provision profiles trying to get it to work. And no dice

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @Rodney I didn't. Then again it may work now, haven't tried since this comment.

Ended up doing the more manual process - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-package-build-ios-production/75208/6.

Has been working for me creating my builds via xCode and Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks - I answered in the Ionic forum.